# Dynamic Permission is not working for single model in cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, authorization, cancan

I did code for dynamically permission from admin side using cancan gem.

when i give permission for all and read / create. it will work but when i give permission for modle_name and read/create. it will show me Access denied. when permission is exist for that.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    logger.info("<.............#{exception.inspect}...........>")
    flash[:alert] = "Access denied. You are not authorized to access the requested page."
    redirect_to user_root_path
  end

  protected
  #derive the model name from the controller. egs UsersController will return User
  def self.permission
    return name = self.name.gsub('Controller','').singularize.split('::').last.constantize.name rescue nil
  end

  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
  end

  #load the permissions for the current user so that UI can be manipulated
  def load_permissions
    @current_permissions = current_user.roles.each do|role|
    end
  end
end


class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user.roles.each do|role|
      role.permissions.each do |permission|
        if permission.subject_class == "all"
          can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.to_sym
        else
          can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.constantize
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

when i give permission like this:

```
permission.subject_class = PublicDoc
permission.action = create
```

is will show me error in console form

```
<....CanCan......:public_doc...........>
<....CanCan......:new...........>
<....CanCan......#<CanCan::AccessDenied: You are not authorized to access this page.>...........>
```

I did some code like this.

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/10/23/dynamic-roles-and-permissions-using-cancan/?blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog

please help me to solve this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my Ability class to this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user.roles.each do|role|
      role.permissions.each do |permission|
        if permission.subject_class == "all"
          can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.to_sym
        else
          can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.to_sym
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and passed value in permission like below.

```
permission.subject_class = public_doc
permission.action = create
```

this is worked for me. 
:)